# Make value of a static object field known to all TU

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a class

```
struct X
{
  static const X  ZERO;

  int  value;

  int  square () const { return value * value; }
  ...
};
```

Then in one TU I define it as

```
const X X::ZERO { 0 };
```

However, other TU don't know anything about the value and so cannot, as I understand, optimize based on such knowledge, e.g. they can't say that `X::ZERO.square()` is 0 at compile time.

Is it possible to somehow have a static field and still have its value known to all TU for optimization purposes? C++11 is fine.

Comment: What does TU stand for?

Comment: You can't have a `constexpr` static data member of the type of the class in the class itself, but you can have a `static constexpr X get_zero();` function.

Comment: Related / duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21008861/420683

Comment: Yeah, the linked question is not exactly a duplicate, but my question seems to boil down to that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you are looking for "Whole Program Optimization".  In Microsoft's compiler, it goes under the name "Link  Time Code Generation".

Comment: Reason for downvote?  WPO is exactly "making definitions from one TU known to all TUs for optimization purposes".