# array of class element as a static constexpr member

Tags: c++, arrays, class, c++11, constexpr

I have a bootstrap problem with a constexpr static member of a class `Bar`
which is an array of `Bar` itself. Consider the following perfectly correct code:

```
struct Foo {
  int i;
  static const std::array<Foo, 2> A;
};
const std::array<Foo, 2> Foo::A {{{1},{2}}};
```

Now I'd like to have `Foo::A` not only const but also `constexpr`. I'm faced
with the problem that static constexpr member initialization must be done
*inside* the class declaration. However, since the declaration is not yet finished,
the compiler doesn't yet know the size of an instance and therefore refuse to
make the array. For example

```
 struct Bar {
   int i;
   constexpr static const std::array<Bar, 2> A{{{1},{2}}};
 };
```

is refused with

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/array: In instantiation of ‘struct std::array<Bar, 2ul>’:
ess.cpp:14:56:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/array:97:56: error: ‘std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::_M_elems’ has incomplete type
       typename _AT_Type::_Type                         _M_elems;
```

Is there a way to solve that ? Or a workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the following solution which ensure that

1. The array is computed at compile time
2. The array is stored in the struct without being copied.

The idea is to use a const reference on a constexpr array.

```
struct Bar {
  int i;
  static const std::array<Bar, 2> &A;
};

constexpr const std::array<Bar, 2> BarA {{{1},{2}}};
const std::array<Bar, 2> &Bar::A = BarA;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible at the moment, the compiler cannot know in advance if the `constexpr` is actually allowed / possible. Replace the member A with a function and it should work:

```
struct Bar
{
    int i;
    constexpr static std::array<Bar, 2> get_A()
    {
        return {{{1}, {2}}};
    }
};
```

Related (almost duplicate): [static constexpr member of same type as class being defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928089/static-constexpr-member-of-same-type-as-class-being-defined)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer which is indeed very close to my problem. I've a question about your solution: does it ensure that the array is indeed computed at compile time and only stored once ? The goal here is to have some kind of multiple singleton class where everything is computed statically.

Comment: It should do what you ask for, but I'm afraid I currently have no means to proove it. My compiler doesn't support `constexpr` yet and it's difficult to verify since you cannot add any informational statements to constexpr-Constructors or do tricks using addresses. However, even if the compiler creates more than one instance, it shouldn't affect runtime performance. And the resulting array should be the same anyway since it's computed at compile-time.

Comment: Actually it doesn't solve the problem. I really want to have a unique array to ensure reference constness. If I do a `static_assert(&Bar::get_A() == &Bar::get_A(), "Duplicate");` Then I got warning that `Bar::get_A()` returns a temporary array and the assert fails.

Comment: Of course it returns a temporary, but the construction of the temporary is already done during compilation. The compiler won't let you take the address of a temporary though,  that's what I meant with "difficult to verify". I'm sorry if it doesn't solve your problem. What if you use a regular const static object but initialize it with a constant expression? Maybe I'm missing something, but to me there isn't much benefit in doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually just to only include the `constexpr` keyword on the *definition*, but **not** the *declaration*:

```
struct Foo {
  int i;
  static const std::array<Foo, 2> A;
};
constexpr std::array<Foo, 2> Foo::A {{{1},{2}}};
```

This ensures that `Foo::A` is defined as an actual constant expression.

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/RbVtOK)

Credit goes to Richard Smith for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21589173/1136311).