# C++ static constexpr field with incomplete type

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to compile this code, but g++ complains about `ZERO` having an incomplete type. Does this mean that in C++ a struct cannot contain a `static constexpr` instance of itself? If so, why?

```
struct Cursor
{
    size_t row,column;

    static constexpr Cursor ZERO {0,0};
    //error: constexpr const Cursor Cursor::ZERO has incomplete type
};
```

EDIT: I understand that `Cursor` cannot have a complete type when I declare `ZERO`. What I'd like to know is: is there any way I can have `ZERO` belonging to `Cursor` and still being `constexpr`?

Comment: could you provide error message?

Comment: I suspect this is because of constexpr & inline initialization.

Comment: Move the initialization outside of the class declaration.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can't do that with static constexpr member.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: You can't, bub.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if I move initialization outside, it is no longer `constexpr`, right?

Comment: OK, you're all right. But the compiler is definitely right, that `Cursor` isn't complete at this point.

Comment: So there's no way I can achieve this?

Comment: If it's public anyway, just declare it outside the class?

Comment: @lodo Well, if you make it a simple `static const` declaration, it could still be used as `constexpr` elsewhere.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Given that `Cursor` is actually defined inside `class VGA`, I'll just make `ZERO` a `static constexpr` member of `VGA`. Sometimes I find certain restriction quite annoying...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unfortunately, you simply cannot do this!

Some `static constexpr` members may be initialised inline:

> `[C++11 9.4.2/3]:` *[..]* A `static` data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the `constexpr` specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression. *[..]*

`Cursor` is a literal type, so this counts.

And the use of `Cursor` itself as a `static` data member within its own type is not a problem, as long as you initialise it at lexical namespace scope:

> `[C++11: 9.4.2/2]:` **The declaration of a `static` data member in its class definition is not a definition and may be of an incomplete type** other than cv-qualified void. **The definition for a `static` data member shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition.** In the definition at namespace scope, the name of the `static` data member shall be qualified by its class name using the `::` operator. **The *initializer* expression in the definition of a `static` data member is in the scope of its class** (3.3.7).

But you can't do that with `constexpr`:

> `[C++11: 7.1.5/9]:` A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`. Such an object shall have literal type and shall be initialized. *[..]*

I think all of this wording could be improved but, in the meantime, I think you're going to have to make `ZERO` a non-member in the enclosing namespace.

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer. Given that Cursor is actually defined inside class VGA, I'll just make ZERO a static constexpr member of VGA. Sometimes I find certain restriction quite annoying...

Answer (score 16):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21589173/1136311) to a similar question revealed that this is, in fact, possible to accomplish. You just have to put the `constexpr` keyword with the *definition* rather than the *declaration*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct Cursor
{
    static Cursor const ZERO;
    std::size_t row, column;
};

constexpr Cursor const Cursor::ZERO{ 0, 0 };

int main(int, char**) noexcept
{
    // using the values in a template argument ensure compile-time usage
    std::array<int, Cursor::ZERO.row> row_arr{};
    std::array<int, Cursor::ZERO.column> col_arr{};
    std::cout << "rows: " << row_arr.size() << "\ncols: " << col_arr.size();
    return 0;
}
```

Fully tested with GCC ([ideone](https://ideone.com/r8pHW5)), clang ([rextester](http://rextester.com/SBC68067)), and MSVC++ 2017 (note that IntelliSense doesn't like it, but it compiles correctly!).

Comment: It does indeed compiles (with C++11/14) but `Cursur::ZERO` is not a `constexpr` in that case. I only managed to make it `constexpr` in C++17 if I inline the definition in the header file `inline constexpr Cursor const Cursor::ZERO{ 0, 0 };`. But do you have any idea to make it `constexpr` in the C++11 ? In other words, it should compile for `constexpr Cursor zero = Cursor::Zero;`.

Comment: Precision, the example above works only for one translation unit. For multiple translation units you need to `inline` the definition of the `ZERO` which if only available from C++17.

Comment: @AlexandreA. depending on your compiler, you can use a class template as an implementation detail. IIRC, MSVC didn't allow that method under C++11, but [this works](https://ideone.com/YWWOTB) on GCC with `-std=C++11` across multiple translation units (of course the link on Ideone isn't representative of that, but I tested it before posting).

Comment: Not sure if this is a compiler bug, but `inline constexpr` of a member field in this manner in multiple translation units under MSVC15 still results in multiple-symbol link errors.

Comment: @Miral I haven't been able to find in the C++17 standard whether this construct is valid or not, though if it isn't then it should result in a compile-time error, not a link-time error.  If the definition has `inline` or `constexpr` and the compiler accepts this yet produces a normal (not linkonce/comdat) data symbol for it, I'd definitely call that a compiler bug.

Answer (score 14):

> is there any way I can have ZERO belonging to Cursor and still being `constexpr`?

Yes, if you count nested subclasses as "belonging to" the containing class:

```
struct Cursor
{
    size_t row,column;

    struct Constants;
};

struct Cursor::Constants
{
    static constexpr Cursor ZERO {0,0};
};
```

Answer (score 10):

You can if you accept to have a function, not a variable

```
struct Cursor
{
    size_t row,column;

    static constexpr Cursor ZERO() { return Cursor{0,0}; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but here's a workaround if all you need is a constant:

```
struct Cursor
{
    struct CursorInit
    {
        int a, b;
        constexpr operator Cursor() const;
    };

    int row, column;
    static constexpr CursorInit ZERO {0,0};

    constexpr bool operator==(const Cursor& rhs) const
    {
        return row == rhs.row && column == rhs.column;
    }
};

inline constexpr Cursor::CursorInit::operator Cursor() const
{
    return Cursor{a, b};
}

static_assert(Cursor::ZERO == Cursor{0, 0});
```

Comment: I appreciate the cleverness. For some library interface I might actually employ this trick.