# Static templated class inside itself

Tags: c++, templates, struct, language-lawyer

We have this kind of code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct A {
    static constexpr A a = A{};
};


template <typename T>
struct B {
    T a;
};

B<A<int>> b;
```

GCC 13 seems happy with L.3 but not clang 16.

```
<source>:3:21: error: constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type 'const A<int>'
        static constexpr A a = A{};
                           ^
<source>:9:4: note: in instantiation of template class 'A<int>' requested here
        T a;
          ^
<source>:12:11: note: in instantiation of template class 'B<A<int>>' requested here
B<A<int>> b;
          ^
<source>:3:21: note: incomplete type 'const A<int>' is not a literal type
        static constexpr A a = A{};
                           ^
<source>:2:8: note: definition of 'A<int>' is not complete until the closing '}'
struct A {
       ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

https://godbolt.org/z/brYMf9har

Which compiler is correct?

Comment: Are you looking for "who is correct" answer specifically (in that case `language-lawyer` tag is warranted) or for something else, e.g. how to satisfy both compilers?

Comment: I'm looking for "who is correct". We do not use clang for now, but CLion detects it as an error, as its inspections are based on clang.

Comment: I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11929560/3854570) is still valid in C++20.

Comment: [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432283/c-static-constexpr-field-with-incomplete-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang is correct.

An object shall not be defined with an incomplete type; [[basic.def]/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def#5). A static constexpr data member is implicitly inline, so its declaration is a definition. And since this definition occurs inside the definition of `A` itself, `A` is still incomplete in this context, unless the context is a complete-class context. The initializer of a static data member is not a complete-class context; [[class.mem.general]/7](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#7).