# Static constexpr members of same type as class defined (additional details)

Tags: c++, c++11, static-members, constexpr

While writing my initial question, if this is even possible, I stumbled about the question [static constexpr member of same type as class being defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928089), which quite clearly answered that my clean solution is not possible with C++11.

But then I came up with this code which is quite close to the original poster and I want to achieve:

```
class MyEnum
{
public:
    constexpr MyEnum() : m_null(true), m_value(0) { }
    constexpr MyEnum(const unsigned int v) : m_null(false), m_value(v) { }

    constexpr operator unsigned int() const { return m_value; }

    static constexpr const MyEnum one() { return MyEnum(1); }

private:
    bool m_null;
    unsigned int m_value;
};
```

So I'm rephrasing my question: Why does the solution for `one` compile and can be used as you would expect it but the following solutions give errors about using an incomplete class?

```
class MyEnum
{
public:
    // snip...

    static constexpr const MyEnum two = MyEnum(2);
    static constexpr const MyEnum three = 3;

    // snip...
}
```

Comment: The bodies of member functions are compiled as if they were located after the class definition. That is, the class is complete within the member function bodies. (See also [CWG 1255](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1255))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @dyp mentioned the solution for `one` compiles because function definitions are compiled after the class body. So it is like `one` has been declared like this

```
class MyEnum
{
public:
    static constexpr const MyEnum one();
    //... Definition here
};  //Class is fully defined after here

inline static constexpr const MyEnum MyEnum::one() { return MyEnum(1); }
                      //Fine here because class is complete ^^^^
```

On the other hand, definitions in the class body are compiled as they are placed in the class body. So when `two` and `three` are being compiled the class is not fully defined yet.