# Move global constexpr class into class as static constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I have some global `constexpr` `Mask`s that I would like to make a part of my `Mask` class as a `static constexpr` to reduce globals in main.cpp

**Currently this works**:

- **main.cpp has**:

  ```
  constexpr Mask cg_completeMask(0xffffffffffffffffull, 0x1ffff);
  ```
- **Mask.hpp has (reduced for SO)**:

  ```
  class Mask {
      unsigned long long m_64;
      unsigned int       m_32;

  public:        
      constexpr Mask(const unsigned long long ac_64, const unsigned int ac_32) :
          m_64(ac_64),
          m_32(ac_32)
      {}
  };
  ```

**What I tried to move the global `Mask`s from main.cpp**:

- **Mask.hpp has**:

  ```
  class Mask {
      unsigned long long m_64;
      unsigned int       m_32;

  public:        
      static constexpr Mask completeMask;

      constexpr Mask(const unsigned long long ac_64, const unsigned int ac_32) :
          m_64(ac_64),
          m_32(ac_32)
      {}
  };
  ```
- **Mask.cpp has**:

  ```
  constexpr Mask Mask::completeMask(0xffffffffffffffffull, 0x1ffff);
  ```

**What I tried produces these errors**:

```
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
Mask.hpp:12:27: error: constexpr static data member 'completeMask' must have an initializer
     static constexpr Mask completeMask;
                           ^
In file included from Mask.cpp:1:0:
Mask.hpp:12:27: error: constexpr static data member 'completeMask' must have an initializer
     static constexpr Mask completeMask;
                           ^
```

Comment: May be duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33177955/static-constexpr-of-class-inside-class-link-problems ?

Comment: @user1034749, Not quite, I have a `static constexpr` member that is not a function member

Comment: Follow this question you can find out that you can not declare constexpr of type `Mask` inside `class Mask` that is your first problem.

Comment: You have 1) an incomplete type inside your type, 2) an infinite recursion of type content: each `Mask` contains a `Mask`. Try to write down the contents of a  `Mask` object on paper. Stop when you reach the end of the page, to save trees. It never ends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I could get was this, which ought to do what you want - but does unfortunately expose your constants in the interface. This is unavoidable I'm afraid.

### * Mask.hpp

```
class Mask {
    unsigned long long m_64;
    unsigned int       m_32;


    // private constructor
    constexpr Mask(const unsigned long long ac_64, const unsigned int ac_32) :
    m_64(ac_64),
    m_32(ac_32)
    {}

public:

    // public declarations
    inline static constexpr Mask complete();
    inline static constexpr Mask partial();

};

// inline definitions
constexpr Mask Mask::complete()
{
    return Mask(0xffffffffffffffffull, 0x1ffff);
}

constexpr Mask Mask::partial()
{
    return Mask(0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0ull, 0x1ffff);
}
```

example of use:

```
auto main() -> int
{
    auto m1 = Mask::complete();
    auto m2 = Mask::partial();

    return 0;
}
```