# Can't a class have static constexpr member instances of itself?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, static-members, incomplete-type

This code is giving me **incomplete type** error.
What is the problem? Isn't allowed for a class to have **static member instances** of itself?
Is there a way to achieve the same result?

```
struct Size
{
    const unsigned int width;
    const unsigned int height;

    static constexpr Size big = { 480, 240 };

    static constexpr Size small = { 210, 170 };

private:

    Size( ) = default;
};
```

Comment: Are you asking specifically about `constexpr` static members ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes. Removing the keyword does'n make it work anyway.

Comment: Once you remove the keyword, you can initialize it ouside the class I guess, when it's already a complete type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [static constexpr member of same type as class being defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928089/static-constexpr-member-of-same-type-as-class-being-defined)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve the same result?

By "the same result", do you specifically intend the `constexpr`-ness of
`Size::big` and `Size::small`? In that case maybe this would be close enough:

```
struct Size
{
    const unsigned int width = 0;
    const unsigned int height = 0;

    static constexpr Size big() {
        return Size { 480, 240 };
    }

    static constexpr Size small() {
        return Size { 210, 170 };
    }

private:

    constexpr Size() = default;
    constexpr Size(int w, int h )
    : width(w),height(h){}
};

static_assert(Size::big().width == 480,"");
static_assert(Size::small().height == 170,"");
```

Answer (score 65):

A class **is** allowed to have a static member of the same type. However, a class is incomplete until the end of its definition, and an object cannot be **defined** with incomplete type. You can **declare** an object with incomplete type, and define it later where it is complete (outside the class).

```
struct Size
{
    const unsigned int width;
    const unsigned int height;

    static const Size big;
    static const Size small;

private:

    Size( ) = default;
};

const Size Size::big = { 480, 240 };
const Size Size::small = { 210, 170 };
```

see this here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f43395e5d08a3952

This doesn't work for `constexpr` members, however.

Comment: Do you think this does not work for `constexpr` members because forbidden by the standard or because of a compiler bug?

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 It doesn't work because a `static constexpr` member is required to be initialized inline.

Comment: What about [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43172652/5376789)?

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround you can use a separate base class which definition is complete when defining the constants in the derived class.

```
struct size_impl
{
//data members and functions here
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
};


struct size:  public size_impl
{
//create the constants as instantiations of size_impl
    static constexpr size_impl big{480,240};
    static constexpr size_impl small{210,170};

//provide implicit conversion constructor and assignment operator
    constexpr size(const size_impl& s):size_impl(s){}
    using size_impl::operator=;

//put all other constructors here
};

//test:
constexpr size a = size::big;
```

You can put the base class in a separate namespace to hide its definition if you want to.

The code compiles with clang and gcc

Answer (score 0):

Another possible workaround is to delay the need for `size`'s definition with the use of templates.

```
template<typename...>
class size {
public:
    template<typename...>
    static constexpr auto big = size{480, 240};

    template<typename...>
    static constexpr auto small = size{210, 170};

    unsigned const width;
    unsigned const height;

private:
    constexpr size() = default;
    constexpr size(unsigned w, unsigned h)
        : width{w}, height{h} {}
};

static_assert(noexcept(size<>::big<>), "");
```

[Live example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/eKh6hPTz6)