# Creating a constexpr enum-like type

Tags: c++, constexpr, type-safety

I've been using `enum class FooEnabled : bool { no, yes };` as a way to create type-safe `bool`s. It works well, except I'd like to add explicit conversion to `bool`, Boolean operators like `operator!`, etc. I can do that like this:

```
template <typename Tag>
class TypedBool {
    bool value;
    explicit constexpr TypedBool(bool b) noexcept : value(b) {}
public:
    static inline TypedBool no{false};
    static inline TypedBool yes{true};
    
    explicit constexpr operator bool() const noexcept { return value; }
    constexpr TypedBool operator!() const noexcept { return TypedBool{!value}; }
    // ...
};

using FooEnabled = TypedBool<struct FooEnabledTag>;
```

That works great, however `no` and `yes` aren't `constexpr`, so I can't do `if constexpr (FooEnabled::yes) {` for example. If I make `no` and `yes` be instead `static constexpr`, clang is upset because `TypedBool` is not a literal type. That appears to be because `TypedBool` is incomplete at that point.

The simplest example of this is `struct S { static constexpr S s; };` which gives

```
error: constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type 'const S'
struct S { static constexpr S s; };
                              ^
note: incomplete type 'const S' is not a literal type
note: definition of 'S' is not complete until the closing '}'
struct S { static constexpr S s; };
```

Is there any way around this? I could make `no` and `yes` be a different type that implicitly converts to `TypedBool<Tag>`, but that seems weird, because then `auto x = FooEnabled::yes;` would make `x` not be a `FooEnabled`, so

```
auto x = FooEnabled::yes;
[](FooEnabled& x) { x = !x; }(x);
```

would fail.

Is there any way to have a class contain `static constexpr` members that are its own type? The solutions I'm starting to think of all seem too ugly to mention (and those also have `constexpr` limitations).

Comment: You can always make `yes` and `no` constexpr functions.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not the enum-like API.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to have a class contain static constexpr members that are its own type?

Yes, there is, just split the declaration from the definition, only the definition needs to contain `constexpr`.

```
struct Foo {
    constexpr Foo(bool b): value(b){}

    static const Foo yes;
    static const Foo no;

    constexpr explicit operator bool() const noexcept{return value;}
    bool value;
};
// Mark inline if in a header.
inline constexpr const Foo Foo::yes{true};
inline constexpr const Foo Foo::no{false};

int main(){

    if constexpr(Foo::yes){
        return 5;
    };
}
```

### Isn't this different declaration vs definition ?

All three compilers g++,clang++,MSCV 19 accept the code above.

But if `Foo` is a template, clang++ doesn't compile the code anymore, as discovered in comments.

There is a [question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172652/static-const-declaration-constexpr-definition-of-variable-valid-c) hinting the standard does not forbid this.
Unfortunately, C++17, C++20 standards are no more explicit either, stating:
The final C++17 draft  requires of [[dcl.constexpr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr)[Empahis mine]

> The constexpr specifier shall be applied only to the definition of a variable or variable template or the declaration of a function or function template.
> The consteval specifier shall be applied only to the declaration of a function or function template.
> A function or static data member declared with the constexpr or consteval specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable ([dcl.inline]).
> **If any declaration of a function or function template has a constexpr or consteval specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the same specifier.**

So my take from this is this is allowed but maybe due to omission rather than deliberation. I did not manage to find any examples in the Standard that would validate this approach.

Comment: Ah thanks, that made me learn something too :)

Comment: Are you sure this works in the original setting? `Foo` needs to be a template. [It looks like clang has a problem exactly with that](https://godbolt.org/z/hxr73x453).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I am confused about the need for tag at all and was addressing the second half of the question. OP can specify any requirements. G++ compiles your example. But I am adding a section because I believe this is slightly grey area.

Comment: The whole idea is to have a bunch of different types that all behave like bool but are not implicitly convertible from bool, or from each other. If you need only one type, just use bool.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Okay, thanks. In that case I do not know whether the code is compliant and clang has a bug. I believe the standard does not forbid this but on the other hand it is not implementable if one would put the definition inside `.cpp` files.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. FWIW I tried moving the template out to an enclosing struct and not surprisingly that didn't help: https://godbolt.org/z/1hfr7csb8

Comment: I can wrap an `enum class` in a templated struct and then overload operators. That almost works and is pretty nice. The one thing there is that there's a distinction I don't really understand between something that's explicitly convertible to `bool` and something that's contextually convertible to `bool`: https://godbolt.org/z/Wqn3M3b7K I didn't realize that `enum class B : bool { no, yes };` had different conversion rules than `struct B { bool b; explicit operator bool() const { return b; } };`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish your goals (supporting `!` operators and explicit conversion to bool) without changing your scoped enumerations.

All scoped enumerations appear to support explicit conversion to `bool`, even if `bool` isnt' the underlying type

```cpp
enum class NotBool : int { No, Yes };
constexpr bool bad = NotBool::Yes; // compile error
constexpr bool yes = bool(NotBool::Yes);
```

You can overload the `!` operator for all scoped enums that have underlying booleans with a template and `std::enable_if`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
constexpr bool HasUnderlyingBool = std::is_same_v<std::underlying_type_t<T>, bool>;

template <typename T>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<HasUnderlyingBool<T>, T> operator !(const T& value) {
    return T(!bool(value));
}

enum class Bool : bool { No, Yes };
static_assert(!Bool::Yes == Bool::No);
static_assert(!Bool::No == Bool::Yes);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest syntax I know works

```
class TypedBool 
{
public:    
    explicit constexpr TypedBool(bool value) noexcept : 
        m_value{ value }
    {
    }

    static constexpr TypedBool no()
    {
        constexpr TypedBool value{ false };
        return value;
    }
 
    static constexpr TypedBool yes()
    {
        constexpr TypedBool value{ true };
        return value;
    }

    explicit constexpr operator bool() const noexcept { return m_value; }

private:
    bool m_value;


};

int main()
{
    constexpr TypedBool value{ true };
    static_assert(value);
    static_assert(TypedBool::yes());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I'd really like to have it look just like `enum class B : bool { no, yes };`.