# constexpr struct member initialisation

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

This code compiles:

```
struct Info
{
    constexpr Info(bool val) : counted(false), value(unsigned(val)) {}
    constexpr Info(unsigned val) : counted(true), value(val) {}

    bool counted;
    unsigned value;
};

constexpr const auto data = std::array{
    Info{true}, Info{42u}
};

struct Foo
{
    constexpr static inline const auto data = std::array{
        Info{true}, Info{42u}
    };
};
```

This code does not:

```
struct Foo
{
    struct Info
    {
        constexpr Info(bool val) : counted(false), value(unsigned(val)) {}
        constexpr Info(unsigned val) : counted(true), value(val) {}

        bool counted;
        unsigned value;
    };

    constexpr static inline const auto data = std::array{
        Info{true}, Info{42u}
    };
};
```

The reported error (in MSVC, gcc, and clang) suggests that they think the `Info` constructor is not defined or is not `constexpr`, eg. from clang:

```
prog.cc:21:5: note: undefined constructor 'Info' cannot be used in a constant expression
    Info{true}, Info{42u}
    ^
```

Why?

(Possibly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381076/static-templated-constexpr-nested-class-member), but `Info` should be complete at the point of use; only `Foo` is still incomplete.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static templated constexpr nested class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381076/static-templated-constexpr-nested-class-member)

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841822/static-constexpr-member-of-an-inner-class

Comment: @KunalPuri I already linked to the first answer and explained why it is inadequate in this case.  The second question has a comment that partly addresses it, but it isn't an "answer" and it doesn't actually make sense for that restriction to exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message of gcc-8 is arguably more clear:

> ```
>    constexpr Foo::Info::Info(bool)’ called in a constant expression before 
>    its definition is complete
> ```

It seems the error is produced according to [expr.const] §2:

> An expression `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract
>   machine (4.6), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> ...
>
> (2.3) — an invocation of an undefined constexpr function or an undefined constexpr constructor;

How come it is undefined, when the call is clearly *after* the definition?

The thing is, member function definitions are delayed until the closing brace of the *outermost enclosing* class (because they can see members of enclosing classes). Consider this class definition:

```
constexpr int one = 1;

struct Foo
{
    struct Bar
    {
        static constexpr int get_one() { return one; }
    };

    static constexpr int two = Bar::get_one() + 1;
    static constexpr int one = 42;
};
```

Assuming this should work, how could an implementation process this definition?

`one` inside `Bar::get_one` refers to `Foo::one`, not `::one`, so it must be processed after that member is seen. It is used in the definition of `two`, which is constexpr, so it must be processed before the initialiser of that member. So for this to work, the overall order must be `one`, then `get_one`, then `two`.

But C++ implementation don't work this way. They don't do any complicated dependency analysis. They process declarations and definitions in order of being seen, with some exceptions listed in [class.mem] §2.

I cannot seem to find an explicit mention in the standard that a constexpr member function is considered undefined until the oitermost enclosing class is complete, but this is the only logical possibility. It cannot work any other way.