# Duplicate symbol linker warnings with constexpr in header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17, constexpr, one-definition-rule

What is the best way to define a `constexpr` variable scoped within its own class?

Conceptually, what I want is this:

```
struct Meow
{
    // constructors etc

    static constexpr Meow Zero{ 0 };
};
```

However [this is not legal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54660899/43534) because within the body of the class itself `Meow` is still an incomplete type and cannot be constexpr-constructed (as dumb as that seems).

---

This works, but isn't constexpr and can't be inlined:

```
// in header file
struct Meow
{
    // ...
    static const Meow Zero;
};

// in cpp file
const Meow Meow::Zero{ 0 };
```

---

This also works, but isn't scoped as desired:

```
struct Meow
{
    // ...
};
inline constexpr Meow Meow_Zero{ 0 };
```

---

This seems to almost work, but generates linker duplicate symbol warnings when the header is used from multiple translation units:

```
struct Meow
{
    // ...
    static const Meow Zero;
};
inline constexpr Meow Meow::Zero{ 0 };
```

resulting in:

```
meow2.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: static struct Meow const Meow::Zero" (?Zero@Meow@@2U1@B) already defined in meow1.obj; second definition ignored
```

or sometimes:

```
cat.lib(meow2.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static struct Meow const Meow::Zero" (?Zero@Meow@@2U1@B) already defined in cat.lib(meow1.obj)
```

(Declaring it `inline const` rather than `inline constexpr` has the same result.)

And yet, this last syntax works without issues if Meow is a template instead (since templates get a secret ODR backdoor).

Comment: "*However this is not legal because within the body of the class itself Meow is still an incomplete type and cannot be constexpr-constructed (as dumb as that seems).*" What is "dumb" about that? The type isn't finished yet. For all the compiler knows, you might introduce another constructor that would make the initialization call a different function. The compiler has no idea how much storage such an object takes up because the type is incomplete.

Comment: It could defer the construction until the end of the class body.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted at the end of the question: indirecting via a dummy template does seem to work, but I'm not happy about it (and am open to better ideas):

```
template<typename T>
struct MeowImpl
{
    // ...
    static const MeowImpl Zero;
};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr MeowImpl<T> MeowImpl<T>::Zero{ 0 };

using Meow = MeowImpl<void>;
```

(This also works if `inline` is omitted, again because template.  Isn't C++ fun?)