# Initialization of static member with same type as class (static initialization order problem)

Tags: c++

Say I have a class `Super`, in which I have a static member of type `Super`, which just defines a commonly used instance of `Super`

```
// super.hpp
class Super
{
public:
    Super(const double a):
        m_a(a)
    {}

    double a() const { return m_a; }

    static const Super thing; // use this a lot in code

private:
    double m_a;
};
```

with implementation

```
// super.cpp
#include "super.hpp"

const Super Super::thing = Super(1.0); // definition
```

At this point I think everything is okay, but please correct me if not.

Now I also have subclasses of `Super`, with similar static members

```
// sub.hpp
#include "super.hpp"

class Sub : public Super
{
public:
    Sub(const double a):
        Super(a)
    {}

    explicit Sub(const Super& obj):
        Super(obj)
    {}

    static const Sub thing;
};
```

with implementation

```
// sub.hpp
#include "sub.hpp"

const Sub Sub::thing = Sub(Super::thing); // WORKS IN MYSTERIOUS WAYS
```

And finally an example usage

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "sub.hpp"

int main()
{
    Super super = Super::thing;
    std::cout << super.a() << std::endl;

    Sub sub = Sub::thing;
    std::cout << sub.a() << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile this with the following setup

```
// CMakeLists.txt
project (hello)
add_executable(hello main.cpp super.cpp sup.cpp)
```

I get the expected output

```
$ ./hello 
1
1
```

but if I change the order of the cpp files in `CMakeLists` (`sub.cpp` before `super.cpp`)

```
// CMakeLists.txt
project (hello)
add_executable(hello main.cpp sup.cpp super.cpp)
```

I get

```
$ ./hello 
1
0
```

I *think* this is an example of [static initialization order ‘fiasco’](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)(?), and I have some understanding of why it happens.

So the question becomes: is there any way to get a warning about an un-initialized static, or any way to avoid the issue?

I've read [How do I prevent the “static initialization order problem”?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use), but I was hoping to be able to keep the `Sub::thing` interface, and avoid replacing it with `Sub::thing()`.

Comment: My constructors are pretty simple (their bodies are empty, I just assign all values in the initialization list), so I probably can do that, but I would need some more guidance in how to do it. I'm not very familiar with `constexpr`.

Comment: I tried making `thing` an `inline static` instead of `static`, but I get an error because `Super` has incomplete type.

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem is that at point, the compiler doesn't see the complete definition of the class. Which is weird, because it doesn't need it at that point. It should work, if `thing` wasn't a member, just a global, outside of the class. I removed my suggestion. I'll try to do this properly later.

Comment: I've found an answer to a similar question that might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32134757/1850917

Comment: Btw., `constexpr` won't work, if you have a destructor, because your type won't be a literal type anymore. Just `inline` for the `thing` variable won't work I'm afraid, because it cannot be used in a `constexpr` context. So maybe, `constexpr` constructor is not the way to do then.

Comment: I don't need a (non-default) destructor.

Comment: Can't you just overload the constructors to create those "commonly used instance"s? Or do you *really* need this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter?

Comment: @Bob__ I can overload the constructor, but think I would need some more info on what exactly you mean. Meanwhile I'll have a look at Nifty Counter.

Comment: I mean that in the example code those static objects are only used to create new instances via copy construction. If this is the only use case, you could just add a default constructor to `Super` and `Sub`. Otherwise, you may add a more complex example to your question.

Comment: Yes, creating new instances via copy is the main use case. But I'm not sure how to get the wanted functionality (`Sub obj = Sub::thing`) via your method. But I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Well, I mean [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jm0GMNmKLeVsoxdZ), but again, it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I did the following:

- made constructors `constexpr`
- made `static` members `constexpr inline` (you have to put them into the header file, not the `.cpp`), so C++17 is needed

Now, your static variables are `constexpr`, so they will be statically-initialized, so the static initialization order fiasco doesn't happen for them.

So, this solution works for me:

```
class Super
{
public:
    constexpr Super(const double a):
        m_a(a)
    {}

    double a() const { return m_a; }

    static const Super thing;

private:
    double m_a;
};

constexpr inline Super Super::thing = Super(1.0);

class Sub : public Super
{
public:
    constexpr Sub(const double a):
        Super(a)
    {}

    constexpr explicit Sub(const Super& obj):
        Super(obj)
    {}

    static const Sub thing;
};

constexpr inline Sub Sub::thing = Sub(Super::thing);

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Super super = Super::thing;
    std::cout << super.a() << std::endl;

    Sub sub = Sub::thing;
    std::cout << sub.a() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This was the exact solution I was working on myself, and it seems to work well. I don't fully understand how I can have the definitions in the headers and not get multiple definition errors, but as long as it works!

Comment: @FilipS.: that's why `inline` needed. If you remove it, you can get linker error.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to get a warning about an un-initialized static,

I don't know

> or any way to avoid the issue?

- You might avoid global member, and use lazy initialization wrapping the global in a function, so changing:

  ```
  // header
  class Super {
      static const Super thing;
      // ...
  };
  //  cpp file
  const Super Super::thing = Super(1.0); // definition
  ```

  to

  ```
  // header
  class Super {
      static const Super& thing();
      // ...
  };
  //  cpp file
  const Super& Super::thing() { static const Super instance{1.0}; return instance; }
  ```

  and similarly

  ```
  class Sub : public Super
  {
  public:
      // ...
      static const Sub thing;
  };

  // sub.cpp
  const Sub Sub::thing = Sub(Super::thing);
  ```

  by

  ```
  class Sub : public Super
  {
  public:
      // ...
      static const Sub& thing();
  };

  // sub.cpp
  const Sub& Sub::thing() { static const Sub instance(Super::thing()); return instance; }
  ```
- Or else place all global in a single translation unit, as order is guarantied.

  ```
  // global.cpp
  #include "super.hpp"
  #include "sub.hpp"

  const Super Super::thing = Super(1.0);    // Defined in order
  const Sub Sub::thing = Sub(Super::thing); // so you have control
  ```

Comment: That works, but my goal was to keep the `Super::thing` interface, which the currently accepted answer does. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: There is still possibility to place the 2 global in same file, as initialization order is guarantied inside a TU.