# Can I initialize a `constexpr static` member outside the class?

Tags: c++

I'm working with a variable-width communications format.  The structs to handle it look something like this:

```
struct Header
{
  int msgType = -1, len;

  Header() { len = sizeof(*this); }
};

struct A : public Header
{
  int x; char y;

  A() { msgType = 1; len = sizeof(*this); }
};

// Further structs B, C, ... declared along the same lines
```

I would like to have a `constexpr static` member `Header::MAX_SIZE` which gives the max size of any of these derived classes, e.g. so I can allocate a buffer which is guaranteed to hold any such packet.  So I'd like to do something like

```
struct Header
{
  int msgType = -1, len;

  constexpr static std::size_t MAX_SIZE;

  Header() { len = sizeof(*this); }
};

// ... declaration of subclasses ...

inline Header::MAX_SIZE = std::max({ sizeof(A), sizeof(B), sizeof(C) });
```

I need the definition to come outside of the class because it depends on `sizeof(A)`, etc., which in turn depend on the definition of `Header`.

It seems like this sort of thing should be unobjectionable: I'm giving the definition of the member in the same source file, and it can be computed at compile time.  But I haven't found any way to tell the compiler to actually do this.

Comment: You can do this readily if you'll settle for `const` rather than `constexpr`. Or is that just not good enough?

Comment: I wanted to use it at compile time.  I guess I can just declare this at namespace scope instead of inside the class, but this seems unnecessary.

Comment: Hmmm. I think a compile-time (constexpr) member of a base class whose value depends on the definitions of derived classes is opening the door to all sorts of recursive circularities. C++20 may have something that addresses this ... I haven't got round to fully digesting that Standard, yet.

Comment: I suppose you'd have to disallow using it from code in between the declaration and the definition.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11928089/103167

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`constexpr` goes on the **initializing** declaration of a variable, so just put it outside the class:

```
struct Header
{
  int msgType = -1, len;

  static const std::size_t MAX_SIZE;

  Header() { len = sizeof(*this); }
};

// ... declaration of subclasses ...

inline constexpr std::size_t Header::MAX_SIZE = std::max({ sizeof(A), sizeof(B), sizeof(C) });
```

Note that the implicit `const` must be spelled out in the declaration.  The definition should go in the **same** header to avoid any translation unit seeing the declaration but not the `inline`, which is not allowed.

Comment: Do you really need the `inline` keyword here?

Comment: @xuhdev: The *intent* is to require it since not doing so is a [regression versus C++14](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2531.html).

Comment: Do you have a reference that your code snippet is equivalent to initializing a `constexpr` static member inside the `struct` definition? I found this example https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static (second last code block) and it looks a bit concerning that initializing a `constexpr` data member may not be allowed outside of the class definition.

Comment: @xuhdev: I don’t understand: it’s declared `constexpr` and is initialized on *that* declaration.  What inequivalence are you supposing might exist?

Comment: I'm Sorry I said it in the wrong way. What I meant is that, would you be sure that your code snippet is standard compliant? I couldn't find any sources that say defining a `constexpr` data member can be done via declaring `const` in class and initializing with `constexpr` out of class.

Comment: @xuhdev: I am sure, but it’s hard to give a citation since the standard doesn’t enumerate every valid sequence of declarations (and it’s not been widely used, as evidenced by the fact that we’re just now finding the bug in C++17).

Comment: @xuhdev Here's a godbolt example showing it working as intended: https://godbolt.org/z/zrEjf9cvE