# Define a static constexpr member of same type of a template class

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, c++20

[A similar question of non-templated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70356275/working-around-limitation-of-constexpr-static-data-member-with-same-type-as-en)

For a template class,

```
template <typename T>
struct Test {
    T data;

    static const Test constant;
};
```

it's fine when defining a `static constexpr` member variable of specialized type:

```
template <>
inline constexpr Test<int> Test<int>::constant {42};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/o4c4YojMf

---

While results are diverged by compilers when defining a `static constexpr` member directly from a template class without instantiation:

```
template <typename T>
inline constexpr Test<T> Test<T>::constant {42};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/M8jdx3WzM

`GCC` compiles.
`clang` ignores the `constexpr` specifier in definition.
`MSVC`... `/std:c++17` works well, but `/std:c++20` rejects due to redefinition.

---

I have learnt that [`constexpr` can be applied to the definition a variable or variable template](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#1.sentence-1)

And in this example, which one is right? Why?

Comment: This is not a member variable template. It is just a member variable. Only `Test` is a template. So naively I don't see why it should be any different from the non-template case.

Comment: @user17732522 You have to instantiate it for every template type that gets used. Except with `inline constexpr` you should be able to do that in the class so it happens automatically.

Comment: It seems that Clang thinks that it doesn't need to implicitly instantiate the definition to determine whether a initializing declaration is reachable. With an explicit instantiation it doesn't complain anymore: https://godbolt.org/z/r15EEnEnY. MSVC's C++20 behavior looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @user17732522 MSVC vigorously follows the idea that `const` and `constexpr` aren't same thing. Member variable specialization have to have same storage qualifiers and member functions - same exception qualifiers.It's consistent among other attempts to specialize a template member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think GCC is correct in [accepting](https://godbolt.org/z/91EbTMvWv) the given example. This is because the `static` data member named `constant` is an **ordinary data member variable**(although it is still considered a **templated entity**).

And since `constant` is an ordinary data member variable, [dcl.constexpr#1.sentence-1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#1.sentence-1) is applicable to it:

> The constexpr specifier **shall be applied only to the definition of a variable** or variable template or the declaration of a function or function template.

(emphasis mine)

Thus, as the construct that you have provided after the class template is nothing but an **out-of-class definition** for the ordinary static data member `constant`, the given example is well-formed.

```
template <typename T>
constexpr Test<T> Test<T>::constant {42};  //this is an out-of-class definition for the ordinary static data member variable `constant`
```

---

##### Note

Note that [dcl.constexpr#1.sentence-1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#1.sentence-1) doesn't mention templated entity, but instead only mention "variable" and "variable template" and since `constant` is a variable(ordinary), the same should be applicable to `constant`.