# How to initialize constexpr static class members per class instantiation basis?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, class-template, explicit-instantiation

Basically, I want to allow the clients of the class `Foo` to define its `static constexpr` member variables using arbitrary values based on the template type argument they pass to it when instantiating `Foo`.

Here is an MRE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>


template < std::unsigned_integral size_type,
           class Allocator = std::allocator<char> >
class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr size_type constant1 { 20 };
    static constexpr size_type constant2 { 30 };

    void dummy_func( ) const
    {
        std::cout << constant1 << ' '
                  << constant2 << '\n';
    }
};

int main( )
{
    Foo<std::uint32_t> fooInstance1;
    fooInstance1.dummy_func( ); // prints: 20 30

    // I want these static members to be initialized
    // by the client but this dummy solution does not work
    // Foo<std::uint64_t>::constant1 { 120 };
    // Foo<std::uint64_t>::constant2 { 130 };

    Foo<std::uint64_t> fooInstance2;
    fooInstance2.dummy_func( ); // should print: 120 130
}
```

Note that the values **20** and **30** are for demonstration purposes and don't need to be inside the class since I want to force the client to decide on their own which values they want their version of `Foo` to have for its `constant1` and `constant2`.

I have also taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67300293/can-i-initialize-a-constexpr-static-member-outside-the-class) similar question but couldn't make it work for the above specific case.

One of the possible approaches that come to my mind is to use *variable templates* instead. But I'm not sure how. Another one is an explicit instantiation of Foo. Or maybe partial instantiation?

Now I want to mention that the class should obviously be able to go in a header file and then be included in whichever source file that needs to instantiate it and use it.

Is there a simple method to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add two non-type template parameters `size_type C1, size_type C2` and initialize `constant1` and `constant2` with those?

Comment: @paolo That's the easiest solution but that's not well suited for my case since there would be too much bloat inside the template argument list because I want to add another type parameter to it. Plus my actual class has about 5 of these static members so having a non-type parameter for each would make it look crazy.

Comment: `static constexpr` is a compile time constant expression. It cannot be changed during runtime.

Comment: @Armin Montigny The client of the API will define those members at compile time. So it should be possible.

Comment: Why does it need to be a compile time constant?

Comment: @digito_evo why you do not use static factory method?

Comment: @sorosh_sabz Could you show me how to do that?

Comment: @digito_evo I post another approach for you, I think it is simple enough and scalable

Comment: @digito_evo I add my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is Foo class has many `static constexpr` variables and writer of Foo class does not like to write long template signature

So I hope to below solution is simple and scalable enough for Foo class writer

```
template <std::unsigned_integral size_type, size_type... args>
class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr size_type constant1{ std::get<0>(internal_values) };
    static constexpr size_type constant2{ std::get<1>(internal_values) };

    void dummy_func() const
    {
        std::cout << constant1 << ' ' << constant2 << std::endl;
    }

private:
    static constexpr std::tuple<size_type, size_type> internal_values{ std::tuple<decltype(args)...>(std::forward<size_type>(args)...) };
};
```

and for use of this class you can just write simple code like below

```
int main()
{
    auto fooInstance1 = Foo<std::uint32_t, 20, 30>();
    fooInstance1.dummy_func(); // prints: 20 30
    auto fooInstance2 = Foo<std::uint64_t, 200, 300>();
    fooInstance2.dummy_func(); // prints: 200 300
}
```

Comment: Seems like a concise and clever solution. I will try this one to see if it works nicely. I think what makes it effective for me is `size_type... args` since it allows me to not put 5 non-type parameters in every declaration of Foo's member functions, right?

Comment: I think you right

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `constexpr` value must be initialized when they are declared. Thus  it look like you have to either do specialization (probably by adding template parameters as suggested in a comment and the derive from that class).

Having said that, if regular static constant works, you can also do :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

template < std::unsigned_integral size_type,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<char> >
    class Foo
{
public:
    // (1) const is used here instead of constexpr
    static const size_type constant1;
    static const size_type constant2;

    void dummy_func() const
    {
        std::cout << constant1 << ' '
            << constant2 << '\n';
    }
};

// (2) Definitions cannot be inside a function.
// (3) Proper syntax must be used to define a constant out-of-class.
// (4) You must provide definition for both 32 and 64 bit since you use both.
// (5) You should have a single definition per type.
template <>
const std::uint32_t Foo<std::uint32_t>::constant1{ 120 };

template <>
const std::uint32_t Foo<std::uint32_t>::constant2{ 130 };

template <>
const std::uint64_t Foo<std::uint64_t>::constant1{ 220 };

template <>
const std::uint64_t Foo<std::uint64_t>::constant2{ 230 };


int main()
{
    Foo<std::uint32_t> fooInstance1;
    fooInstance1.dummy_func(); // prints: 120 130

    Foo<std::uint64_t> fooInstance2;
    fooInstance2.dummy_func(); // prints: 220 230
}
```

With that, you will get the following output :

```
120 130
220 230
```

Why are you specifying an allocator parameter? Do you intent to specify distinct constants for each allocator?

Comment: But this doesn't ensure the static members to be compile time evaluated, right? Also, do you think variable templates can do any sort of help here?

Comment: Well, this is mostly like your original code but with compilation errors fixed...

Comment: Then probably partial or full template specialization is what you want... It should be easy to find example online.

Comment: Tnx, I guess I'll look into the partial specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Seems overly complex. If client shall set both constants, why you do not write a constructor with parameters?

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename size_type,
class Allocator = std::allocator<char> >
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(size_type c1=20, size_type c2=30) :
        constant1(c1),
        constant2(c2) {}
    const size_type constant1;
    const size_type constant2;

    void dummy_func() const
    {
        std::cout << constant1 << ' '
            << constant2 << '\n';
    }
};


int main()
{
    Foo<std::uint32_t> fooInstance1;
    fooInstance1.dummy_func(); // prints: 20 30
    
    Foo<std::uint64_t> fooInstance2(120, 130);
    fooInstance2.dummy_func(); // should print: 120 130
}
```

I removed the `<concepts>` stuff, its C++20 and I am stuck with C++14.
What I do not understand:

**Are these constants specific to the type of size_type?**

If yes, why then should a Client (User) of your Foo class set these values? You should better provide a non-template implementation of your Foo class  for all needed types with the correct constants. (of course each implementation may inherit from your template class)

**Are these constants independent of the type of size_type?**

If yes, why then should they be static constexpr? What if two Clients want to instantiate your class with different constants?

You should always have a solid reason to even think about writing the word "static". Static is mostly evil (I know... its just my opinion).